# How to show custom view on each screen on dismiss of a controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to show a custom view on a dismiss of a controller. It's working fine if I am sowing it on popViewController but not working when I am using dismiss method. If anybody knows the solution please help me out.

```
 // presenting screen from HomeController

guard let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "EmptyWorkout", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogWoroutVC") as? LogWorkoutViewController else { return }
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

// dimissing screen from LogWorkoutViewController  

@IBAction func backButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.last
    let timerView = UINib(nibName: "WorkoutTimer", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? WorkoutTimer
    if let timerView = timerView {
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        if let tabBarYPosition = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.y {
            let yPosition = tabBarYPosition - 60
            timerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yPosition, width: screenWidth, height: 60)
            window?.addSubview(timerView)
        }
        
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

Comment: can you show your present viewcontrioller code

Comment: yes I have added the presenting screen code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, the presenting controller is responsible for the actual dismiss. When the presented controller dismisses itself, it will ask the presenter to do it for it. In here you need to use the closure or protocol. for e.g use like

on your LogWorkoutViewController VC / presented VC declare the variable as like

```
 var dismissedVC : ((Bool) -> Void)?
```

There is a Boolean property inside `UIViewController` called `isBeingDismissed` that you can use for this purpose:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if isBeingDismissed {
        // TODO: called the closures
       dismissedVC!(true)
    }
}
```

on your button action call only dismiss VC

```
 @IBAction func backButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

on your HomeController when you present call the closure also.

```
    guard let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "EmptyWorkout", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogWoroutVC") as? LogWorkoutViewController else { return }
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
controller.dismissedVC = { result in
            // call your WorkoutTimer view
          self.workoutTimer()
        }
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)





 func workoutTimer() {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.last
        let timerView = UINib(nibName: "WorkoutTimer", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? WorkoutTimer
        if let timerView = timerView {
            let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
            let screenWidth = screenSize.width
            if let tabBarYPosition = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.y {
                let yPosition = tabBarYPosition - 60
                timerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yPosition, width: screenWidth, height: 60)
                window?.addSubview(timerView)
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```